# Bundle problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I can't seem to get the javascript files to update in VS2013, asp.net using bundles.  The image is after I have done a clean/rebuild, bundle clear and resetall, and deleted the browser history in IE (including cookies, website data, temp files and website files.)  I have wasted day after day trying to get my site working.  I have googled this a hundred times and found no satisfactory answers.  What am I missing?  There has got to be an easy way to do this.

[image: Outdated javascript file]

Comment: Restart the "server". Stop debugging then restart it again. That should do the trick.

Comment: I just tried that and it did not work.  Can you clarify "Restart the server"?  It runs in IIS Express which shuts down when I stop debugging.  In VS2010 it used to stay running, but in 2013 it goes away when you stop.

Comment: The javascipt file is out of date.  In the image, you can see that it is loading the latest version, but the new code never gets hit because  the app is actually running the old code. You can see that it tells me that the file is not the same and should be reloaded.  But I can't get it to reload short of wiping it out with a nuclear explosion.

Comment: Nobody has any idea how to get bundles to update properly?

Comment: Just don't use bundles during development at all, they're simply not working as expected most of the time. There's some convention over configuration in the way the bundles are named that are not entirely clear or documented. Just do it yourself until bundles are fixed and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, don't use bundles during development of javascript or CSS files at all.

Just comment out the part where the bundle is rendered and include the corresponding files the classic way like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/myscript.js?v=@DateTime.Now.Ticks" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When deploying the project remove that line and reactivate the previously commented bundle-rendering call.

Because the uri-parameter version string of the "classic-approach" is changing on each request you can be sure that you always have the latest version of javascript file and are not dependent on some CacheDependency of the Bundle-Framework to trigger or update (which apparently is not working all of the time).

Just don't forget to remove that manual script include so that your users' browsers can actually cache the resources.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer even though I have not tested it yet because it sounds reasonable to me.  I appreciate you answering this.  :-)

Comment: Also, it's very difficult to reproduce this behavior since Most of the time it is working. But only most of the time. If it works, the Bundling Feature is absolutely amazing. One of the great web dev improvements since VS 2010 - 2013. But when this bug surfaces during the last stages right before freezing a RC it can be really painful.